# Get Value from a lambda

Tags: python, lambda

how could i get the value click_type in the expression below, as I would like to compare it at a later stage of the script?

```
cc.on_button_single_or_double_click_or_hold = lambda channel, click_type, was_queued, time_diff: \
        print(click_type)
```

Comment: Can you please provide the context? when will you provide the input to the lambda function? did you write the above line yourself / copy it from somewhere?

Comment: I am using a library and am able to get value of click_type by the above code only. i would like to be able to compare this to 3 different strings. how can i do this

Comment: I got this working cc.on_button_single_or_double_click_or_hold = lambda channel, click_type, was_queued, time_diff: print("1 click") if str(click_type) == 'ClickType.ButtonSingleClick' else print("double click") if str(click_type) == 'ClickType.ButtonDoubleClick' else print("button held")
but i am limited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anywhere you can use a lambda, you can also define a function. So how about this?

```
def record_click(click_type=None):
    """
    Save each click seen in a list
    """
    try:
        cache = record_click.cache 
    except AttributeError:
        record_click.cache = []
    if click_type is not None:
        cache.append(click_type)
    return cache

def handle_click(channel, click_type, was_queued, time_diff):
    """
    Report each click, then record it for later
    """
    print(click_type)
    record_click(click_type)

cc.on_button_single_or_double_click_or_hold = handle_click
```

Elsewhere in your code:

```
def foobar(...):
    """
    Look at the most recent click
    """
    click_list = record_click()
    if click_list[-1] == ???:
        do something
```

The function record_click stores a list of clicks as they come in. When you call it with no arguments, it will return the list to you. click_list[-1] gets the most recent click, the last one in the list.